# subset matching columns but keep rows

Tags: r

I'm looking for a solution for following problem: I have 2 dataframes with multiple columns. When certain columns of the dataframes match I want to subset the rows  as well. In this case columns of V1, V2 and V8 should match. The output (intersection) should contain also the rows. Appreciate any help.

Example

df1

```
row.names   V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8
1799    4   100333846   401070          C   C   1   1   hom
1936    21  38934599    exm-rs4372192   A   A   1   1   hom
1937    2   12790328    exm-rs1000053   G   G   1   1   hom
```

df2

```
row.names   V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8
1   1   762273      rs3115849   G   A   0   1   het
2   21  38934599    rs4372192   A   G   1   1   hom
3   1   877715      rs6605066   C   G   1   1   hom
```

Comment: May be use `merge` by specifying the columns to match in the `by`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best bet is, https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/merge.html

```
merge(df1,df2,by=c("V1","V2","V8"))
```